# OpenStack: Setting up network devices error out

Tags: linux, networking, openstack

```
[root@OpenStack-1 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-enp0s3
DEVICE=enp0s3
HWADDR="08:00:27:8E:EA:56"
TYPE=OVSPort
DEVICETYPE=ovs
OVS_BRIDGE=br-ex
ONBOOT=yes
```

-

```
[root@OpenStack-1 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-br-ex
DEVICE=br-ex
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSBridge
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=192.168.1.254
ONBOOT=yes
```

I get this error on a network reboot.

```
systemctl restart network
Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Looked in the log:

```
-- Unit network.service has begun starting up.
Oct 15 18:01:47 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Oct 15 18:01:47 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: Bringing up interface br-ex:  ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Device br-ex does not seem to be present, de
Oct 15 18:01:47 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth[3219]: Device br-ex does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
Oct 15 18:01:47 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: [FAILED]
Oct 15 18:01:48 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: Bringing up interface enp0s3:  ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Device enp0s3 does not seem to be present,
Oct 15 18:01:48 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth[3250]: Device enp0s3 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
Oct 15 18:01:48 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: [FAILED]
Oct 15 18:01:48 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: Bringing up interface eth0:  RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: [  OK  ]
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com network[3105]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 15 18:01:49 OpenStack-1.openstack.internal.srvhost.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
```

This is all virtualized under Hyper-V am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First questions: It's your openvswitch installed and running ?. If its not, ensure it's installed and running by issuing the following commands:

```
yum -y install openvswitch
service openvswitch start
chkconfig openvswitch on
```

Also, try to manually create the bridge and ports, then restart your server:

```
ovs-vsctl add-br br-ex
ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex enp0s3
reboot
```

Let me know how it goes !.

More info here:

https://github.com/tigerlinux/openstack-mitaka-installer-centos7/blob/master/DOCS/NOTES.txt

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have invalid `enp0s3` device in network configuration. It may be from a previous installation. Just delete these files and restart network again.

```
rm -f /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3
rm -f /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br-ex
```